# C++ pass a child as a parent to a function

Tags: c++, inheritance

so here's a simplified version of my setup:

```cpp
class GenericSensor{
public:
    int read(){
        return something;
    }
};

class SpecialSensor : public GenericSensor{
public:
    int read(){
        return somethingElse;
    }
};
```

and I have a function:

```cpp
void someFunction(GenericSensor s){
    printf("value is: %d\n", s.read());
}
```

how do I make `someFunction` work with `GenericSensor`, `SpecialSensor` or any other derived class's object?

Comment: Look up polymorphism.

Comment: Whatever C++ book you are learning from, keep reading.  Polymorphism should be covered in an early chapter.

Comment: Remember, by passing a parent pointer to a function, the function should only use the methods and members of the parent class.  If you want the function to use child class methods or members, they should be moved up to the parent.  Read up on "C++ slicing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `read()` as a `virtual` function which `SpecialSensor`, or any other derived class, can `override`.

Moreover, you should not pass `GenericSensor` around by value, otherwise you will [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) the caller's object. Rather, pass it around by pointer or reference instead. So have `someFunction()` receive `s` by `GenericSensor*` pointer or `GenericSensor&` reference.

Comment: didnt know virtual functions are a thing, thanks for the big hint